# Show that $\frac{a}{a+1}+\frac{b}{b+1}\geq\frac{a+b}{1+a+b}\geq\frac{c}{1+c}$ whenever $c\leq a+b$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I found a post on ME [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1241393/459435).
It sais:

> Try to show that $$\frac{a}{a+1}+\frac{b}{b+1}\geq\frac{a+b}{1+a+b}\geq\frac{c}{1+c}$$ whenever $c\leq a+b$

I wasn't able to solve this. How does it work?

Comment: I can give an answer with calculus. Is that preferable, or should I stick to ordinary AM-GM etc.

Comment: See: [Given positive real numbers $a, b, c$ with $a<b+c$, show that $a/(1+a)<b/(1+b)+c/(1+c)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672881)

Comment: Just study the function $x\to \dfrac{x}{1+x}.$ (Draw the graph. Look at the derivative, concavity and....)

Comment: Why was this question down-voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that,

$$\frac{a}{1+a} \ge \frac{a}{1+a+b} $$

and

$$\frac{b}{1+b} \ge \frac{b}{1+a+b} $$

Adding the above two equations.
$$\frac{a}{1+a} + \frac{b}{1+b} \ge \frac{a}{1+a+b} + \frac{b}{1+a+b} $$

$$\frac{a}{1+a} + \frac{b}{1+b}\ge \frac{a+b}{1+a+b} $$

Now assume $a+b = k$

Given

\begin{align}
& a+b \ge c 
\\ &\Rightarrow k \ge c 
\\ &\Rightarrow k + 1 \ge c + 1 
\\ &\Rightarrow \frac{1}{k + 1} \le \frac{1}{c+ 1} 
\\ &\Rightarrow -\frac{1}{k + 1} \ge -\frac{1}{c + 1} 
\\ &\Rightarrow 1-\frac{1}{k + 1} \ge 1 -\frac{1}{c + 1} 
\\ &\Rightarrow \frac{k}{k + 1} \ge \frac{c}{c + 1} 
\\&\Rightarrow \frac{a+b}{1 + a+ b} \ge \frac{c}{c + 1}
\end{align}

Hence Proved

$$\frac{a}{1+a} + \frac{b}{1+b}\ge \frac{a+b}{1+a+b} \ge \frac{c}{c + 1}$$

Comment: This is dope. Thank you very much! +500 ;-)